# Populate a DataGridView with a DataView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, dataview

I would like to fill in my DataGridView with a DataView that we can assume already contains data. I have been searching for a way to do this but all the solutions involve other data structures than a DataView or involve using other libraries that I am unable to encorporate in this project. Do I need to first convert the DataView to something else and use that to populate the DataGridView? Or  is there something else I can use than a DataGridView that displays information in a similar way?

Comment: Apparently I can just use the Table property of the DataView and use that as the DataSource for the DataGridView. I'll try it out and put that as the solution if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `DataSource` property of `DataGridView` to your `DataView`.
A `DataSource` can implement either the `IBindingListView` or `IList` interfaces (with other options that are irelevant to this case.) that are both implemented by the `DataView`.

For more information check the MSDN:

- [Displaying Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171600.aspx)
- [Data Display Modes in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd28yf6d.aspx)
- [DataGridView.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)
- [DataView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Bind a DataView Object to a Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669070.aspx)

This is all native, I just googled "datagridview.datasource to dataview" maybe I mis-read and this doesn't solve your problem but comment if so and I will try and help

```
private void GetData()
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize the DataSet.
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        // Create the connection string for the AdventureWorks sample database.
        string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
            + "Integrated Security=true;";

        // Create the command strings for querying the Contact table.
        string contactSelectCommand = "SELECT ContactID, Title, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Phone FROM Person.Contact";

        // Create the contacts data adapter.
        contactsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
            contactSelectCommand,
            connectionString);

        // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
        // delete commands based on the contacts select command. These are used to
        // update the database.
        SqlCommandBuilder contactsCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(contactsDataAdapter);

        // Fill the data set with the contact information.
        contactsDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Contact");

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```